# QRCode AddressBook type String to Vcard

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, vcf-vcard

After scanning the "ADDRESSBOOK" type from QR code, the content that I get is the simple string like:

```
  Sandeep
  abc
  def
  ;;my new address
  +908888888888
  +901111111111
  +902222222222
  homeemail@example.com
  workemail@example.com
   http://www.google.com
```

Now I want to convert this string into vCard and open the address book of the device(phone) with all these contents filled on the specific column...I researched a lot but no Idea. Please guide me into this.

**EDIT:**

check this QR code:
[image]

I have created this vCard type QR code using http://goqr.me/

but after scanning, It just shows the content, not in the vCard format. But I want to convert this simple comtent into vCard.

Please help..

Answer (score 1):

What does each line your code sample represent?  The vCard would look something like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Sandeep
ADR:;;123 Street;City;Region;PostalCode;Country
TEL:+908888888888
TEL:+901111111111
TEL:+902222222222
EMAIL;TYPE=home:homeemail@example.com
EMAIL;TYPE=work:workemail@example.com
URL:http://www.google.com
END:VCARD
```

Comment: yes exactly..I am saying the same that it is not the VCard, It's type is "ADDRESSBOOK". SO now I have to change this ADDRESSBOOK type string into VCard..

Comment: After scanning from QR code, I am getting the this content only:

Comment: Sandeep
  abc
  def
  ;;my new address
  +908888888888
  +901111111111
  +902222222222
  homeemail@example.com
  workemail@example.com
   http://www.google.com